# Why is the code not working for the following input as the nodes of the tree

Tags: python, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

[5,1,4,null,null,3,6]
this is the input for which my code is failing -The expected output is False but I am getting True as the output.
The link for the question i have written the code is -https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/submissions/

`

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def isValidBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:

        def lcheck(rt,c,rb4,rflux=None): #rb4=ROOT BEFORE,# rflux=root after which the direction changed
#C=0 Means the outermost branch of the tree                                                                     
            if rt:
                if c==0:
                    if rt.val>=rb4.val:
                        return False
                    lcheck(rt.left,0,rt,rflux=None)
                    rcheck(rt.right,1,rt,rb4)
                if c==1:
                    if rt.val>=rb4.val or rt.val<= rflux.val:
                        return False
                    lcheck(rt.left,1,rt,rflux)
                    rcheck(rt.right,1,rt,rb4)
        def rcheck(rt,c,rb4,rflux=None):
            if rt:
                if c==0:
                    if rt.val<=rb4.val:
                        return False
                    lcheck(rt.left,1,rt,rflux=rb4)
                    rcheck(rt.right,0,rt,rflux=None)
                if c==1:
                    if rt.val<=rb4.val or rt.val>= rflux.val:
                        return False
                    lcheck(rt.left,1,rt,rb4)
                    rcheck(rt.right,1,rt,rflux)
        lcheck(root.left,0,root)
        rcheck(root.right,0,root) 
        return True
```

`
above is my code

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `isValidBST` function *always* returns True. It makes the calls to `lcheck` and `rcheck` but then ignores their return values, and just returns `True` no matter what.

Secondly, those `lcheck` and `rcheck` functions never return `True`. They also suffer from the same problem described above: they make recursive calls, but then ignore the values these calls return. In many cases they don't execute a `return` statement at all, so that they return `None` instead of a boolean.

Here is your code with the fixes needed to address above points:

```
    def isValidBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:

        def lcheck(rt,c,rb4,rflux=None):                                          
            if rt:
                if c==0:
                    if rt.val>=rb4.val:
                        return False
                    return lcheck(rt.left,0,rt,rflux=None) and rcheck(rt.right,1,rt,rb4)
                if c==1:
                    if rt.val>=rb4.val or rt.val<= rflux.val:
                        return False
                    return lcheck(rt.left,1,rt,rflux) and rcheck(rt.right,1,rt,rb4)
            return True
        def rcheck(rt,c,rb4,rflux=None):
            if rt:
                if c==0:
                    if rt.val<=rb4.val:
                        return False
                    return lcheck(rt.left,1,rt,rflux=rb4) and rcheck(rt.right,0,rt,rflux=None)
                if c==1:
                    if rt.val<=rb4.val or rt.val>= rflux.val:
                        return False
                    return lcheck(rt.left,1,rt,rb4) and rcheck(rt.right,1,rt,rflux)
            return True
        return lcheck(root.left,0,root) and rcheck(root.right,0,root)
```

With these changes the code works as intended, but honestly it is overly complex. Instead of passing bounding *nodes* as arguments, you could pass the corresponding *values* as arguments, representing the "window" of values that are allowed. The `c` parameter can be omitted if you initialise that window with -Infinity to Infinity. If you do that, and make sure the window parameters are given with first the low bound and then the high bound, then you can also replace `lcheck` and `rcheck` with just one function for both.